# Matlab find string within cell array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell

I have a cell array (n-by-1 dimension) containing both strings and cells, which looks something like this

```
{
{'r1'}     % -> cell content is in format 'char'
{'r2'}     % -> cell content is in format 'char'
{1x2 cell} % -> cell content is a cell array: [{'r1'}{'r2'}]
{'r3'}     % -> cell content is in format 'char'
{1x2 cell} % -> cell content is a cell array: [{'r1'}{'r3'}]
{1x2 cell} % -> cell content is a cell array: [{'r2'}{'r3'}]
{1x3 cell} % -> cell content is a cell array: [{'r1'}{'r2'}{'r3'}]
...
}
```

I need to find the row-index where the some string is included, e.g. 'r2'. I usually use `strfind` for this purpose which works great if the cell array has a consistent format (hence 'char'-format within each cell).

Is there any way to apply this function to the cell array structure which is displayed above?

Thanks!

EDIT: Please find attached three images showing the data structure that I am using, since I am not sure how to exactly show/explain the hierarchies and layers of the cell array in text. Hope that helps. Also find attached the outcome of the code.

Code used:

```
change = 'r1.m';
srch = cellfun(@(x) strfind(x, change), strats, 'UniformOutput', false);
stringInRow = cellfun(@(x) numel(x) == 1 || (numel(x)>1)*numel(cell2mat(x))>0, srch);
rows = find(stringInRow);
```

[image: cell array]

[image: example of cell array within cell 5,1]

[image: last "layer" in char format]

[image: outcome in 'srch']

[image: outcome of logical operation on srch]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use two subsequent `cellfun` calls: one to perform the string search (cell by cell), and one to evaluate it (found string `true` or not `false`?)

```
%// example data
c{1} = 'r1';     
c{2} = 'r2';    
c{3}{1} = 'r1'; c{3}{2} = 'r2';
c{4} = 'r3';
c{5}{1} = 'r1'; c{5}{2} = 'r3';

%// example search
searchForString = 'r2';
srch = cellfun(@(x) strfind(x, searchForString), c, 'UniformOutput', false);
stringInRow = ...
  cellfun(@(x) numel(x) == 1 || (numel(x)>1)*numel(cell2mat(x))>0, srch);
               %// ^-. short-circuit scalars here     ^
               %//                                    |
               %// since cell2mat is valid only for cells or empty arrays
```

With resulting `stringInRow`:

```
stringInRow =

     0     1     1     0     0
```

If you want to explicitly list the rows, you can just make use of `find` on the `stringInRow` boolean vector

```
>> foundStringInRows = find(stringInRow)

foundStringInRows =

     2     3
```

Comment: a little mistake: looks like you mean use `c{3}{2}` second time instead of `c{5}{2}`.
Can you clarify please, why searching in this cell array returns this answer? As I can see it mast be `0 1 1 0 0` because `c{2}='r2'` and `c{3}{2} = 'r2'`. So why it is `0 1 0 0 1`?

Comment: I guess I beat you to fixing my own mistake (within 5 minutes also :) ) just prior to your comment. With this fix, search returns `0 1 1 0 0`, as it should. Good catch though!

Comment: ahh, really! I have had to refresh it first! You are too fast ;D

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! The example works perfectly and does what I would like to achieve. However, when I apply it to my data and does not produce the correct results. The problem appears to be that when I produce `search`, all cells will contain another cell array (of different sizes). Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: @Benvaulter Are you sure that your data is a _cell array_, and not a _single cell containing a cell array_? If the latter, start by extracting the actual cell array (e.g. `cArr = c{1}`). If this is not the issue, please show us a fully verifiable example how (a subset) of your data looks like.

Comment: @dfri Please see updated question above. Hope the pictures clearify the data structure as I find it hard to explain exactly how they are laid out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Benvaulter Thanks for your detailed addition. That is strange, I agree that the issue seems to be that `srch` is a cell array (ok) but with all members being cells themselves: they should be scalars or empty vectors for members in `strats` that are not cells themselves. What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: @Benvaulter Anyway, since all elements in `srch` is (always?) cells themselves, you can use a simpler version of calculating `stringInRow` above, which doesn't use short-circuting for scalars. Try replacing your use calulation of `stringInRow` with: `stringInRow = cellfun(@(x) numel(cell2mat(x))>0, srch);`

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help - I appreciate it!

Comment: @Benvaulter Happy to help. Out of curiosity, what version of Matlab are you using? (Since for me, R2015b, I needed to use the longer `stringInRow` solution above).

Comment: Interesting - I am using R2015a - maybe there have been some slight changes in the way cellfun works?

Comment: @Benvaulter I wrote wrong, I'm actually also using R2015a, which makes this even more peculiar. Possibly some setting, or something with your specific `strats` cell array that differs from my example. I'll look into the former (setting?), and if I can't find anything there, perhaps this mystery will remain unsolved :)